# Variable isnt properly checked in if statement

Tags: game-maker

[image]

Somehow I can spam "Q" to have the if statement run infinetly as if the cooldown never gets checked for or never Updated

I wanted to have like a cooldown timer of 60 Frames and only have this Sequences playable when the cooldown is off. But smh I can Spam it as often as I want

Answer (score 1):

You should define the `meele_cooldown = 60` (melee?) in the Create Event, rather than inside the function itself. Because as you mention it, if you repeately press 'Q', it'll get redefined.

You should then set the `meele_cooldown` back to 60 after when it hits 0.

Edit:

With the added context from the comment, I've expanded my answer a bit further:

You should put the countdown condition `if (attack_cooldown >= 1)` and place it outside your `Keyboard_Check_pressed()`, because you want that to cooldown regardless if you've pressed or not. You should also improve your condition to make sure it's 0 if it's done counting down. As the variables are decimals.

So the end result may look like this:

```
if (attack_cooldown >= 0)
{
    attack_cooldown -= 1;
}
else 
{
    attack_cooldown = 0;
}

if (keyboard_check_pressed() ... && attack_cooldown == 0)
{
    attack_cooldown = 60;
    //create sequence object
}
```

As a sidenote: I do notice that you're using a sequence now, I'm not familiar with that myself, but I assume you want that to play during the cooldown. I think that fits better if it's in it's own Step Event rather than the event of an other object. Because a temporary variable will lose it's value after the Step Event is done.

Comment: (Yea sorry im not a native english speaker lol. I renamed it to Attack_cooldown now since I wanna use it for different weapons later aswell.)

I have it set to 0 in the create Event. I want the attack to be useable at 0 and reset back to 60 every time I attack. 

So I should only be able to attack once the cooldown hits 0 (Its set to 0 in the Create Event aswell) So the first thing I want to happen, is to set the cooldown to 60 so i should be locked out from attacking again. I also tried setting it back to 60 when it hits 0 but I am not getting the results I expect/need

Comment: I see, thanks for the context. I've updated my answer to show a possible solution for the attack_cooldown.

Comment: it still does not work. Also the sequence is made specifically for this object, which is also why I even need a cooldown. No Sequence = No Attack.
The cooldown is for the attack animation itself so it wont play multiple of them at once.

As a sidenote. I also sometimes struggle with frame drops if I spam the sequence too many times and the frames wont come back, even after the sequence end. Im assuming its because its not performing the "layer_sequence_destroy" correctly in some instances. Ive tried manipulating the code by moving some lines around. (Like in and out of if statements etc.)

Comment: okay I mostly fixed the Issue, using the help above. But now Im running into another issue. I now dont know how to delete the sequence. If I run the destroy_sequence in the if statement, it gets destroyed immediately and the animation doesnt play. If I dont destroy it, it remains invisible after playing once, which adds lag